# Converting html helper to .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 4.6.2 I have an HTML helper that looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString JsMinify(this HtmlHelper helper, Func<object, object> markup, bool shouldMinify)
{
    string notMinifiedJs = (markup.DynamicInvoke(helper.ViewContext) ?? "").ToString();

    var minifier = new Minifier();
    var minifiedJs = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(notMinifiedJs, new CodeSettings
    {
        EvalTreatment = EvalTreatment.MakeImmediateSafe,
        PreserveImportantComments = false
    });
    return new MvcHtmlString(minifiedJs);
}
```

It is used like this:

```
@Html.JsMinify(@<text>
// some cool javascript here
</text>)
```

In .NET Core 3.1 I am trying to recreate a similar helper:

```
public static IHtmlContent JsMinify(this IHtmlHelper helper, Func<object, object> markup)
{
    var resultTemplate = markup.DynamicInvoke(helper.ViewContext);
    var notMinifiedStr = (resultTemplate ?? string.Empty).ToString();
    var minifiedStr = Uglify.Js(notMinifiedStr, UglifyCodeSettings);
    return new HtmlString(minifiedStr.Code);
}
```

However, it's not working correctly. Debugging this, I can see **notMinifiedStr** value is a string "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.HelperResult" which is totally wrong. I am not very sure what is different here for .NET core.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Why not put the Javascript in separate `.js` files and have ASP.NET Core minify it, along with the other files in `wwwroot`?

Comment: That is a good idea, but not as easy because right now C# populates some of the values in this javascript. I may still do this, but it would require a lot of refactor.

Comment: You can pass those as parameters. In fact, you could do that with the original code too - although the tooling integration in 4.6 was a bit ... lacking.

Comment: Have you tried returning a string directly? [This minifier is rather ugly](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/minifying-inline-css-js-html-using-taghelpers-in-aspnet-core) but in the end returns a string. I'd also look into tools that minify all the JS code in a page, as a first step to extracting the code to separate files. Once you start having even modest amounts of JavaScript code, you need to move to files, for sanity's sake

Comment: TagHelpers are very neat! Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using TagHelpers like this:

```
public class ScriptTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private static readonly CodeSettings UglifyCodeSettings = new CodeSettings { PreserveImportantComments = false, EvalTreatment = EvalTreatment.MakeImmediateSafe, MinifyCode = true };

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
        }

        var js = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(js))
        {
            var minifiedStr = Uglify.Js(js, UglifyCodeSettings);

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(minifiedStr.Code);
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply adding this line at the top of the cshtml files I needed processing:

```
@addTagHelper *, InsertYourAssemblyNameHere
```